# since upgrading my software to 4.1 my samsung galaxy note wont charge properly

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, charging, samsung-galaxy-note

I recently upgraded the software on my galaxy note to 4.1 and since then its been very strange when charging. I put it on charge last night woke up this morning it said charging 23% came back to it a few minutes later and it said charging 18% I took the battery out and then back in and it said charging 8%. I took my charger to work with me and charged it through the day and noticed that sometimes it charges but will keep to the same percentage for hours or even though it says charging the amount of charge decreases. Does anyone have any ideas? Cheers

Comment: Are you charging from mains or via a PC?  Have you tried a different lead/plug, or a different PC?

Comment: Car charger and 2 different mains chargers. This morning I woke up it said 100% I unplugged the mains cable and it went down to 23%